# Python multiprocessing: more processes than requested

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Why do I see so many python processes running (in `htop` on `RHEL 6`) for the same script when I only use 1 core?

[image]

For each task, I init a worker class that manages the processing. It does init other classes, but not any subprocesses:

```
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    num_consumers = 1

    consumers = [Consumer(tasks, results) for i in xrange(num_consumers)]
    for i, consumer in enumerate(consumers):
        logger.debug('Starting consumer %s (%i/%i)' % (consumer.name, i + 1, num_consumers))
        consumer.start()
```

Note, `atop` shows the expected number of processes (in this case 2: 1 for the parent and 1 for the child). The %MEM often adds up to well over 100% so I gather I'm misunderstanding how multiprocessing or htop works.

Comment: It looks like htop is showing you every thread running inside the process. Compare `ps -ef` to `ps -eLf` (`-L` adds threads to the output).

Comment: Alternatively, you can type `H` in htop to hide/show user threads.

Comment: Threads! Thanks, probably should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're seeing helper threads spun up by the Multiprocessing module within the main pid from your app. These are in addition to the Threads/Processes you've spun up explicitly.