# Strange process clone appears with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I have faces a very strange behavior of Python. It looks like when I start parallel program which uses multiprocessing and in the main process spawn 2 more(producer, consumer) I see 4 processes running. I think there should be only 3: the main, Producer, Consumer. But after some time the 4th process appears.

I have made a minimal example of the code to reproduce the problem. It create two processes in which calculate Fibonacci numbers using recursion:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import os, sys
import time
import signal

def fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1
    result = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    return result

def worker(queue, amount):
    pid = os.getpid()
    def workerProcess(a, b):
        print a, b
        print 'This is Writer(', pid, ')'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, workerProcess)

    print 'Worker', os.getpid()
    for i in range(0, amount):
        queue.put(fib(35 - i % 4))
    queue.put('end')
    print 'Worker finished'

def writer(queue):
    pid = os.getpid()
    def writerProcess(a, b):
        print a, b
        print 'This is Writer(', pid, ')'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGUSR1, writerProcess)

    print 'Writer', os.getpid()
    working = True
    while working:
        if not queue.empty():
            value = queue.get()
            if value != 'end':
                fib(32 + value % 4)
            else:
                working = False
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
    print 'Writer finished'

def daemon():
    print 'Daemon', os.getpid()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def useProcesses(amount):
    q = Queue()
    writer_process = Process(target=writer, args=(q,))
    worker_process = Process(target=worker, args=(q, amount))
    writer_process.daemon = True
    worker_process.daemon = True
    worker_process.start()
    writer_process.start()

def run(amount):
    print 'Main', os.getpid()
    pid = os.getpid()
    def killThisProcess(a, b):
        print a, b
        print 'Main killed by signal(', pid, ')'
        sys.exit(0)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, killThisProcess)
    useProcesses(amount)
    print 'Ready to exit main'
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

def main():
    run(1000)

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

What I see in the output is:

```
$ python python_daemon.py 
Main 13257
Ready to exit main
Worker 13258
Writer 13259
```

but in htop I see the following:
[image: Demonstration of htop]
And it looks like the process with PID 13322 is actually a thread. **The question is what is it? Who spawn it? Why?**
If I send SIGUSR1 to this PID I see in the output appears:

```
10 <frame object at 0x7f05c14ed5d8>
This is Writer( 13258 )
```

This question is slightly related with: [Python multiprocessing: more processes than requested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903946/python-multiprocessing-more-processes-than-requested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The threads belongs to the Queue object.

It uses internally a thread to dispatch the data over a Pipe.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue):

> class multiprocessing.Queue([maxsize])
>
> Returns a process shared queue implemented using a pipe and a few locks/semaphores. When a process first puts an item on the queue **a feeder thread is started** which transfers objects from a buffer into the pipe.